# "call not sent" popup

Tags: android, call, galaxy

I have a frustrating issue with blocking & delivering calls.

My App flow is as follows:

1. Broadcast receiver BR that receive intents of `NEW_OUTGOING_CALL`, stops the call (by `setResultData(null);` ) and starts a service S.
2. S decides whether to call or not (and show a dialog). If it decides to call it `startActivity()` with `ACTION_CALL` with the `NEW_TASK` flag. (and put some identifier so  the next time the BR will receive it it wont block it.

This flow works great till now, **but on Galaxy S3 it has a problems**:

1. It only blocks the call - the startActivity() of the new call doesn't work.
2. I assume that it happens because the system is still processing on the first request and dropped the new call.
3. I tried to call abortBroadcast(); from the BR but the I got the "call not sent" oppup which means that the system still dealing with that intent
4. I succeded to get the desired functionality by putting a post-delay in the service so the will be a little timespan between the two calls.

**Can I achieve the desired functionality without post-delay the new call?**

Comment: have you tried adding priority to your receiver?

Comment: Yes, I tried both priority:100 and priority:0, both behave the same in that case. Both has the same behavior on GS3.